# Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2 because no repositories are defined

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[image]I upgraded the gradle version to 5.4.1 in an old project, and encountered the following problems. The reference address of the project is https://github.com/lyc7898/AndroidTech
I modified the configuration of the build.gradle file, as shown below

Comment: You should post the relevant gradle-scripts with such a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **project's** `build.gradle` buildscript

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
```